# Find the first row and last row of available data

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

> I have set-up a macro which looks into another workbook and copies the 1st sheet of that workbook and brings it into the original workbook. The code works fine but I'd like to add some extra logic which automatically locates the first and last rows of the available source data. Currently I have it set up so the code copies anything starting from cell "A1" until the last row. But I'd like to make sure that in cases where the data starts e.g "B2", I want the code to recognize that and ignore Row A and bring in anything that starts from "B2" until last row and paste everything in the original workbook starting on cell A1...I hope that paints the picture. Part of the code below: Thank you all.

```
If myFile Like "*Import*" then
Set wb = workbooks.open(fileName:=myPath & myFile)
With wb.sheets(1)
lrow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
.Range("A1:XFD" & lRow).copy ws4.Range("A1")
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for `UsedRange` which can be used such as

```
Sub testmeout()
    Dim copy_ws As Worksheet, to_ws As Worksheet
    Set copy_ws = Worksheets(1)
    Set to_ws = Worksheets(2)

    ' use range value assignment of equal sizes for instant copy and paste
    ' (no format though)
    Dim copy_rng As Range, to_rng As Range

    Set copy_rng = copy_ws.UsedRange
    Set to_rng = to_ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(copy_rng.Rows.Count, copy_rng.Columns.Count)
    to_rng = copy_rng.Value

End Sub
```

You can also test out `ActiveWorksheet.UsedRange.Address` in your immediate window (ctrl+G in editor) to see the exact range before running.